# Entering password through keystroke fails

Tags: applescript, shortcuts-app

I was automating password entry for an application using shortcuts,

First used shortcut action,

```
Open application_name
```

then wrote AppleScript,

```
on run
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke {return}
        delay 2
        keystroke "password"
        delay 2
        keystroke {return}
    end tell
end run
```

but it gives me authentication failed.

And when I type the same password manually, then authentication succeeds, is there an alternative to using keystroke?

Answer (score 1):

Was able to solve this problem by using key code instead of keystroke.
Not really sure about the reason for keystroke to not work.
But using key code works as of now.

Comment: if you're going to use 'keystroke', you have to deal with setting the shift state.  Do your passwords have anything other than lower case characters?

Comment: they have capital characters, special characters, numbers.